# Finding primes $p$ and $q$ such that $p$ divides $q^2 -4$ and $q$ divides $p^2-1$

Tags: number-theory

Finding all sets of primes $p$ and $q$ such that $p$ divides $q^2 -4$ and $q$ divides $p^2-1$.

Comment: I tried equating $q^2-4$ to np where n is an integer. I did the same for the next equation, But that way it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint :

$p$ divides $q+2$ or $q-2$ and $q$ divides $p+1$ or $p-1$

Consider one by one case :

$p=l(q+2),q=m(p+1)\Rightarrow p=l(m(p+1)+2)=lmp+lm+2l\Rightarrow p= ??$

try other cases...

- $p=l(q+2),q=m(p-1)$
- $p=l(q-2),q=m(p-1)$
- $p=l(q-2),q=m(p+1)$

Comment: We get p = $\frac{l(m+2)}{1-lm}$. What after that

Comment: what would this say about $q$... can both be primes for some $l,m$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  $q^2-4$ and $p^2-1$ can be factored.

Comment: What after that

Comment: $q$ divides one of $p-1$ and $p+1$, and $p$ divides one of $q-2$ and $q+2$.  But either $q \le p$ or $p \le q$ ...

Answer (score -1):

Four cases would be formed and only two would be left .

$p+1 \equiv 0 \pmod q$

$q+2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$

After some estimation it would be found that only $p=5$ and $q=3$ can be the solution.